# UIButton with left+right caps and a middle pattern

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

How can I create a `UIButton` with a background image which is composed by:

1. A fixed *left* cap
2. A fixed *right* cap
3. A number of *middle images* placed one after the other to fill all the available space

like in the example below?

[image: UIButton]

**EDIT:** I did not realize that in the center there are no *N* repeated images, but only a streched one. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Do the middle images follow a fixed pattern like your example? Eg. 2 pixels green and 2 pixels white?

Comment: Hi! No, caps and middle images _are all attached_, without white spaces.

Comment: I've added a [reference guide link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:) to the answer. You can specify whether the resizable center part should be **tiled** or **stretched**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it cannot be done. What you can do is stretch an image, but you cannot add n middle images.

The code for adding a stretchable image in between is

```
//Create an image - Where UIEdgeInsets is in top left bottom right
UIImage* buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];

// Create a custom buttom
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, buttonImage.size.height);
[myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Add it to view - if it is a view controller self.view
[self addView:myButton];
```

From Apple's [UIImage Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:):

> "**resizableImageWithCapInsets:**
>
> You use this method to add cap insets to an image or to change the existing cap insets of an image. [...] During scaling or resizing of the image, areas covered by a cap are not scaled or resized. Instead, the pixel area not covered by **the cap in each direction is tiled**, left-to-right and top-to-bottom, to resize the image." *[emphasis added]*

You can read more about it at http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html